# How to change the default time-zone used by: spark.read.jdbc while reading from SQL Server

Tags: scala, jdbc, databricks

I am using Databricks Runtime 4.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.3.1, Scala 2.11)

On a Scala notebook, when I read data from SQL Server 2012 via JDBC with a command like this:

val data_frame = spark.read.jdbc( , ,  )

All the SQL Server DATETIME columns on my source table are mapped to TIMESTAMP columns in the data frame with a default time-zone of +0000.

Is there a way to change the default time zone of +0000 that is assigned on the fly to let’s say: -0700 (MTS)?

NOTE: If possible, I would like not having to travers all the TIMESTAMP columns to then apply a transformation, instead, I would like to change the behavior of the JDBC driver telling it to use a different time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Add "**serverTimezone=****" to your jdbc connection string.

Comment: From a quick search it looks like that's the MySQL answer but I can't find any references that say this works for SQL Server too. The string 'serverTimezone' doesn't appear in the [JDBC driver source](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) for example.